# custom html5 video controls jquery

Tags: jquery

I have found the following code to add custom html5 video controls.

html:

```
    <div>
<video id="video" controls>
   <source src="/images/videos/LargeRoom.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="grass-in-the-wind-sma.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<div id="controls">
<button id="playpause" title="play" onclick="togglePlayPause()">Play</button>
</div>

</div>


<div>
<video id="video" controls>
   <source src="/images/videos/LargeRoom.mp4" type="video/mp4">
   <source src="grass-in-the-wind-sma.webm" type="video/webm">
</video>

<div id="controls">
<button id="playpause" title="play" onclick="togglePlayPause()">Play</button>
</div>

</div>
```

and the following javascript:

```
   // Grab a handle to the video
   var video = document.getElementById("video");
   // Turn off the default controls
   video.controls = false;


   function togglePlayPause() {
   var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
   if (video.paused || video.ended) {
      playpause.title = "pause";
      playpause.innerHTML = "pause";
      video.play();
   }
   else {
      playpause.title = "play";
      playpause.innerHTML = "play";
      video.pause();
   }
}

video.addEventListener('play', function() {
   var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
   playpause.title = "pause";
   playpause.innerHTML = "pause";
}, false);
video.addEventListener('pause', function() {
   var playpause = document.getElementById("playpause");
   playpause.title = "play";
   playpause.innerHTML = "play";
}, false);
```

The issue I am having is that both play/stop buttons control the top first video. As oppose to each controlling their own video.

Comment: **ID of an element must be unique** - in your case use class to select the video control related to the clicked button

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cqvdx6bt/2/

Comment: Brilliant, thank you

Comment: Arun P Johny- I have copied your jsfiddle which is great, only issue is once the video has played the pause button remains rather than change back to play button

Comment: try the ended event http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/cqvdx6bt/3/

Comment: Thanks, all working!

Answer (score 2):

The IDs of the elements in the DOM must be unique. You should try to call your methods by the class names like this:

```
// Grab a handle to the video
var video = document.getElementsByClassName("video");
```

And here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pedromendessk/qsnmd3mw/1/) with your code running properly only using javascript. Although I think the code would be much simple and clean if you used jQuery.

Hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Arun P Johny cleaned it up and posted the jsfiddle. Just having an issue with the pause button remaining now

Comment: And with the code in my fiddle you still have that issue?